# Rails + Paperclips + Rackspace CloudFiles with the Private CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rackspace-cloud, fog, cloudfiles

I have a Rails application that uses Paperclip to handle uploaded files and we are currently hosted by Rackspace.

The application is currently hosted on a single server and I am building out a more scalable solution with load balancers, application servers, and a separate database server. The last thing I need to do is a solution for the uploaded assets. I have tried to use Rackspace's CloudFiles, but it seems the only way to use paperclip and CloudFiles is to have them on the public CDN, which I can't use, a user needs to be authenticate to access the files. Before I turn to Amazon S3, since they have the option for temporary URLs, does know how to use CloudFiles with Paperclip and require authentication to access the files?

Any help, tips, google searches, links, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Really interesting question/idea. I use this same setup for uploading client files in our app at work: Rackspace, Paperclip and Rials (v3.2.17) but have not had to implement this security measure. I found this example on the fog Github site for creating a private directory: https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/rackspace/examples/storage/create_private_directory.rb (wonder if that might lead you down the necessary path?)

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, Cloud Files [also supports](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/rackspace/models/storage/file.rb#L182-L198) the generation of temporary URLs, and [it appears that Paperclip does allow you to make use of it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb#L141-L154). Just generate the URL from your `Attachment` with `#expiring_url` instead of `#url` in your views:

```
= image_tag @organization.logo.expiring_url(Time.now.to_i + 100, :original).gsub(/^http:/, "https")
```

Paperclip will [only generate http urls](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb#L143-L144), but since Rackspace's temporary URLs don't use the scheme in their checksums, you can use a `gsub` call to turn it into an https URL. Also, notice that the first argument to `#expiring_url` is an *absolute* timestamp (in seconds-since-the-epoch).

Expiring URLs for Rackspace only made it into fog somewhat recently -- v1.18.0 -- so if you're using an older version, you may need to upgrade fog to take advantage of them:

```
bundle upgrade fog
```

Paperclip also supports [generating obfuscated URLs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/416), which looks interesting, but would be less secure, since the server wouldn't expire it.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the response. It has gotten me most of the way there. I now can get actual urls for the files, but I get an error when the image tries to load "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I think I have to set the rackspace_temp_url_key but I can't figure out how. Any ideas?

Comment: Paperclip passes `:fog_credentials` as-is to `Fog::Storage`, so you should be able to add it there: `:fog_credentials => { :provider => 'rackspace', ..., :rackspace_temp_url_key => ENV['SUPER_SECRET_KEY'] }`

Comment: I've added the temp url key, but now I can't seem to figure out how to set the key.

Comment: That should be the only place you need to set it :-) Fog remembers the temp URL key that you set when Paperclip instantiates `Fog::Storage` and uses it to generate the signature in the temporary URL. Are you still unable to download them with the `expiring_url`?

Comment: I've been able to add it there and I do get a link, but I have not yet been able to add it on the Rackspace side. I'll update this comment if I find a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, great, let me know. I'm ash.wilson@rackspace.com if you want to contact me offline (and I'll edit my answer with the eventual resolution for the benefit of the rest of the Internet ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the key like this:

```
class Rackspace

  def self.add_temp_url_key
    require 'fog'

    puts "Creating Storage Service"

    begin
      service = Fog::Storage.new(
        :provider => 'rackspace',
        :rackspace_username => ENV['FOG_USERNAME'],
        :rackspace_api_key => ENV['FOG_API_KEY'],
        :rackspace_region => ENV['RACKSPACE_REGION'].to_sym
      )

      service.post_set_meta_temp_url_key(ENV['RACKSPACE_TEMP_URL_KEY'])
      puts "X-Account-Meta-Temp-Url-Key successfully set to #{ENV['RACKSPACE_TEMP_URL_KEY']}"

    rescue => e
      puts "Unable to set X-Account-Meta-Temp-Url-Key - #{e.inspect}"
      puts e.backtrace
    end
  end

end
```